# How do I fix a database error after login?

Tags: php, mysql, mediawiki

MediaWiki version: 1.30.0

PHP version: 5.6.40 (litespeed)

Hello. I attempted to log into a non-English version of my wiki on the same LocalSettings.php and file manager data as the English wikis, and this occurred:

```
[Xdk7ZAQM3-8wuBBN0db3IgAAAI8] /mw19/index.php?title=Speciala%C4%B5o:Ensaluti&returnto=%C4%88efpa%C4%9Do Wikimedia\Rdbms\DBQueryError from line 1149 of /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php: A database query error has occurred. Did you forget to run your application's database schema updater after upgrading?
Query: SELECT user_id,user_newpassword,user_newpass_time FROM `gjlxrtap_mw19758`.`mwd50q_user` WHERE user_name = 'Newman2' LIMIT 1
Function: MediaWiki\Auth\TemporaryPasswordPrimaryAuthenticationProvider::beginPrimaryAuthentication
Error: 1142 SELECT command denied to user 'gjlxrtap_mw3333'@'localhost' for table 'mwd50q_user' (localhost)
Backtrace:

#0 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php(979): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->reportQueryError(string, integer, string, string, boolean)
#1 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php(1343): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->query(string, string)
#2 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/libs/rdbms/database/Database.php(1411): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->select(string, array, array, string, array, array)
#3 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/auth/TemporaryPasswordPrimaryAuthenticationProvider.php(137): Wikimedia\Rdbms\Database->selectRow(string, array, array, string)
#4 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/auth/AuthManager.php(452): MediaWiki\Auth\TemporaryPasswordPrimaryAuthenticationProvider->beginPrimaryAuthentication(array)
#5 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/auth/AuthManager.php(382): MediaWiki\Auth\AuthManager->continueAuthentication(array)
#6 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/specialpage/AuthManagerSpecialPage.php(353): MediaWiki\Auth\AuthManager->beginAuthentication(array, string)
#7 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/specialpage/AuthManagerSpecialPage.php(482): AuthManagerSpecialPage->performAuthenticationStep(string, array)
#8 [internal function]: AuthManagerSpecialPage->handleFormSubmit(array, VFormHTMLForm)
#9 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/htmlform/HTMLForm.php(669): call_user_func(array, array, VFormHTMLForm)
#10 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/specialpage/AuthManagerSpecialPage.php(416): HTMLForm->trySubmit()
#11 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/specialpage/LoginSignupSpecialPage.php(316): AuthManagerSpecialPage->trySubmit()
#12 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/specialpage/SpecialPage.php(522): LoginSignupSpecialPage->execute(NULL)
#13 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/specialpage/SpecialPageFactory.php(578): SpecialPage->run(NULL)
#14 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/MediaWiki.php(287): SpecialPageFactory::executePath(Title, RequestContext)
#15 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/MediaWiki.php(851): MediaWiki->performRequest()
#16 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/includes/MediaWiki.php(523): MediaWiki->main()
#17 /home/gjlxrtap/public_html/mw19/index.php(43): MediaWiki->run()
#18 {main}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Looks like you need to give your db user `gjlxrtap_mw3333` proper access to your tables

Comment: If you have to guess the error. What is the error message saying?

Comment: @ThanhTrung What do you mean by what the error message says?

Comment: Well, it clearly says `SELECT command denied to user` no? This is a right permission problem.

Comment: How do I fix/use the SELECT command?